# How to add attribute to div, when using Handlebars JS?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am using [Handlebars JS](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to add elements from a template. The Handlebar template looks like this:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="case-item">{{title}}</div> 
</script>
```

**Script**

```
// create a handlebars template
var source = document.getElementById('item-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

**Dataset**

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([{        
    title: 'This is a test title'
}
```

**Result**

When I run the code, the `<div class="case-item">` only shows `<div>` it doesn't create the attribute `class="case-item"`

```
<div>This is a test title</div>
```

and not

```
<div class="case-item">This is a test title</div>
```

Any ideas why it "strips" the attribute?

Comment: Can you try that: `var items = new vis.DataSet([{        
    title: 'This is a test title',
    class: 'case-item',
}
`

Comment: @MaikLowrey Thank you for answering - I've just tried it, and it doesn't make a difference. I also tried adding <div class="{{class}}">.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error. Are you running Handlebars in a real browser or in Node.js with JSDom or similar?

Comment: @GOTO0 Node.js in vscode on "live server" extension, and viewing on Chrome. Do you think it has something to do with that? :)

Comment: Possibly so. I suppose that if you add a `console.log(source);` in your script, it will print `<div>{{title}}</div>` without `class="case-item"`?

Comment: @GOTO0 - It actually prints it with the attribute class="case-item". I'm using Vis timeline (https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/). Maybe it's the one, that strips the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution, to go around the Handlebar issue described in the question.

I chose to follow the [Vis Timeline Custom Styling example](https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo5/documentation/general/vis-timeline/style.html)